# How can I get the score I wanted by using KerasRegressor and sklearn pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, pipeline

I want to insert Keras model into scikit-learn pipeline, but when I use pipeline.score, I am comfused. Here is the code:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor  
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(
        layers.Dense(
            64, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_data.shape[1], )))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model


model = KerasRegressor(
    build_fn=build_model, epochs=90, batch_size=1, verbose=0)

pipe_network = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()), ('clf', model)])
pipe_network.fit(train_data, train_targets)
```

The model score is:

```
pipe_network.score(test_data, test_targets)
>>> -12.813292971994802
```

What's the score is? I want to get the result like the output of evaluate function, How can I do?

```
stdsc = StandardScaler()
train_data_std = stdsc.fit_transform(train_data)
test_data_std = stdsc.transform(test_data)

network = build_model()
network.fit(train_data_std, train_targets, epochs=90, batch_size=1, verbose=0)

network.evaluate(test_data_std, test_targets)
>>> [12.681396334779029, 2.479423579047708]
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: [The docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasRegressor#score) say that `.score` returns the mean loss.  How -12.8 could possibly be the mean square error, I haven't a clue.  Does your data include complex numbers?  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot,my data is from keras's dataset. (train_data, train_targets), (test_data,test_targets) = boston_housing.load_data().